# usage of camera blocks NFC reading/writing

Tags: java, android, android-camera, nfc

We have developed an Android application with Android Studio that can use the camera to scan a QR code, selecting an associated content (a bunch of data) and then write said content via NFC onto a NFC tag.

Implementation and testing on multiple devices went all good until we tested on a Samsung S21 with Android 11, where we found a particular issue: whenever the app made use of the camera, any subsequent NFC write or read would not work, tags were simply not picked up anymore by the system.

This issue seems to appear on Android 11 devices only, previous versions all work fine.
We tried to "detach" from most of the app code to isolate the camera and NFC functionalities and we still reproduce the issue on this minimal-scale application (source code [here](https://github.com/ThomasRuvoletto/camera-nfc-test)).
We have three fragments (Home, Camera and Nfc) and we can switch between the three; Nfc works fine and can detect and read a tag, camera works fine on its own and can pick up QR codes, but whenever we use camera first (either picking up a code or tapping "back"), the nfc will not work anymore.

We make sure to release the Camera properly but with no results. This is our camera fragment:

```
public class CameraFragment extends Fragment {

    private FragmentCameraBinding binding;
    private CameraSource cameraSource;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(
            @NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState
    ) {
        binding = FragmentCameraBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        return binding.getRoot();
    }

    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        BarcodeDetector detector = new BarcodeDetector.Builder(requireActivity()).build();
        this.cameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(getActivity(), detector).build();

        binding.cameraSurfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(@NonNull SurfaceHolder holder) {
                try {
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireActivity(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, MainActivity.CAMERA_PERMISSION_CODE);
                        return;
                    }
                    cameraSource.start(holder);
                } catch (IOException ignored) {
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(@NonNull SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(@NonNull SurfaceHolder holder) {
                cameraSource.release();
                cameraSource = null;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        binding = null;
    }
}
```

and this is the NFC fragment:

```
public class NfcFragment extends Fragment {

    private FragmentNfcBinding binding;
    private NFCAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        binding = FragmentNfcBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        return binding.getRoot();
    }

    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        adapter = new NFCAdapter(getActivity());
        adapter.EnableReaderMode();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        binding = null;
        adapter = null;
    }
}
```

We've gathered very little info around the web but most are pointing towards an issue on Android 11. We tested with the same result another Android 11 device (a different Samsung).
Are we doing something wrong here?

For now, we found a workaround that seems to hold: we simulate the "going on background" and the resume of the app (pause and resume of MainActivity) when we release the camera:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
   this.context.onPause();
   this.context.onResume();

   super.onDestroy();
}
```

but it's not a pleasant solution.

What could the culprit be? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If this is the same issue as on e.g. the Nexus 5X then it's not related to the Android version, but rather to a hardware design issue: the camera hardware and the NFC hardware are located in such a way / operating in such a way that they interfere with one another. The solution is to never attempt to use both features simultaneously, i.e. make sure you have stopped the camera before attempting to use NFC, and vice versa.

Comment: I've not seen anything in the Android source code that would cause the issue but as @Michael says I suspect that it might be a low level hardware problem of how the hardware communicates with the CPU (interrupts and whatever protocol they use e.g. SPI, I2C, etc) or issue with how the low level drivers for the hardware.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. While it might be some hardware condition, it would make more sense to me if it didn't work when using camera and nfc simultaneously; on our case where we use the feature separately I would expect it to work. Which brings me to @Michael point: is a `CameraSource.release();` enough to properly stop the camera?

Comment: Forgot to mention: CameraSource implementation is [this](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/blob/master/visionSamples/barcode-reader/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/samples/vision/barcodereader/ui/camera/CameraSource.java).
It uses android.hardware.Camera.

Comment: Well, `surfaceDestroyed` might be too late to stop/release the camera (or put another way: `onViewCreated` might be too early to start using NFC). You'll have to check when these things happen relative to one another, and make sure that the camera has been stopped before you attempt to start using NFC. Whether that means stopping the camera earlier or starting NFC later is up to you.